# PHP + Javascript parent function not getting called

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, function, parent

Alright I've been trying to find an answer to this for hours already but I couldn't resolve it myself.
I'm trying to call a Javascript parent function from a PHP function, however, it is not getting called.
When using the onclick method `onclick='parent.dosomething();` everything seems to work fine but if I try to call the function by echo'ing it out, it would just fail for some reason.

```
echo "<script>parent.reloadprofmessages();</script>"; //this is what is not getting called
```

Here's the PHP function:

```
function checkactivity($username)
{
    //These are just queries being executed (irrelevant)

    $querystats = "SELECT users.fullname, activity.id, activity.sender, activity.receiver, activity.type, activity.dateposted, activity.seen, activity.related FROM activity, users WHERE activity.receiver = '$username' && activity.seen = '0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $resultstats = mysql_query($querystats);
    $num_stats = mysql_num_rows($resultstats);
    $rowactivity = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultstats);

    //End of queries

    if($num_stats > 0) //If there are registries
    {
        $user = $_SESSION['Username'];

        $activity_date = $rowactivity["dateposted"];
        $activity_type = $rowactivity["type"];
        $activity_sender = $rowactivity["sender"];
        $timeactivity = strtotime( "$activity_date" );
        $actualtime = time();

        $timetoseconds = $actualtime - $timeposted; 
        $timetominutes = floor($timepassedtoseconds/60);

        if($timetominutes < 2)
        {
            if($activity_sender != $user)
            {
                if($activity_type == 1) //Messages
                {
                    echo "<script>parent.reloadprofmessages();</script>"; //this is what is not getting called
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And this is my Javascript function at the parent page:

```
function reloadprofmessages()
{
    $('#friendrequests').load('showprofmessages.php?username=<?php echo $actualuser; ?>').fadeIn("slow");
} //refreshes messages
```

I pressed CTRL + Shift + I in Google Chrome to get to the developer tools, Network > page that does the request that calls the PHP function > Preview and this was what I received:
`<script>parent.reloadprofmessages();</script>`
However, the function is not getting called.
Resolving this would solve me a lot of problems, to me it is actually still a mystery to know why it doesn't work since it has worked in other cases.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't try to use this method of invoking javascript with php. What happens if you need multiple calls to this js method? You wouldn't want to keep echoing out <script> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to fetch javascript and execute it with AJAX. What I would suggest is to firstly change your PHP to this:

```
if($activity_type == 1) //Messages
{
    echo "1";
}
else {
    echo "0";
}
```

Then change your Javascript to this:

```
function reloadprofmessages()
{
    var can_reload = $.ajax({ url: "showprofmessages.php?username=<?php echo $actualuser; ?>" });
    if (can_reload) {
        parent.erloadprofmessages();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I'll try that method and will tell you what happened, thanks.

Comment: You see, just because you fetch some script tags and insert them into the DOM, it doesn't mean the javascript inside of them will be executed. Actually, this is disabled in some instances intentionally as a security precaution. It is better to use an ajax query to get a value which is then used by pre-loaded javascript to act upon, as in the example above.

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't seem to work, I guess this is happening because reloadprofmessages() is not getting called from anywhere, which means that I still have to call it.
The reason I was doing this was because I would save bandwidth by not echo'ing out a lot of text. (echo'ing text less often by doing calls and such)

Comment: Ok, but the parent.reloadprofmessages() is being called by the javascript in the child script. So basically, you are calling your php which returns either a 1 or a 0 and storing it into can_reload. If can_reload is 1, then you call parent.reloadprofmessages().... OH, please note that I spelled the function incorrectly int he answer above.

Comment: After working around and reading, I found out what was wrong with what I was trying, I kind of used your example but decided to use $ajax.get() instead.
I'll explain detailedly below. (answering my question)

Comment: Well, it seems that I can't answer it myself for at least six hours.
But thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the type attribute for script tag

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript' >parent.reloadprofmessages();</script>";
```

and remember to define the javascript function before this line

Answer (score 0):

So here is what was wrong: (Showing errors)

```
function checkactivity($username)
{
    //These are just queries being executed (irrelevant)

    $querystats = "SELECT users.fullname, activity.id, activity.sender, activity.receiver, activity.type, activity.dateposted, activity.seen, activity.related FROM activity, users WHERE activity.receiver = '$username' && activity.seen = '0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $resultstats = mysql_query($querystats);
    $num_stats = mysql_num_rows($resultstats);
    $rowactivity = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultstats);

    //End of queries

    if($num_stats > 0) //If there are registries
    {
        $user = $_SESSION['Username'];

        $activity_date = $rowactivity["dateposted"];
        $activity_type = $rowactivity["type"];
        $activity_sender = $rowactivity["sender"];
        $timeactivity = strtotime( "$activity_date" ); //$timeactivity was not being used
        $actualtime = time();

        $timetoseconds = $actualtime - $timeposted; //$timeposted doesn't even exist, in other words I wasn't even converting the $activity_date timestamp to time.
        $timetominutes = floor($timepassedtoseconds/60);

        if($timetominutes < 2)
        {
            if($activity_sender != $user)
            {
                if($activity_type == 1) //Messages
                {
                    echo "<script>parent.reloadprofmessages();</script>"; //this was not the correct way of calling a function from the parent page.
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

About the Javascript function:
This is what I ended with:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function reloadstring()
{
        $.get("checknewactivity.php?vprofile=<?php echo $actualuser; ?>", function(activity){
        if (activity == 1) 
        {
            $('#profcommentsdiv').load('showprofmessages.php?vprofile=<?php echo $actualuser; ?>').fadeIn("slow");
        }
        });
}, 1000); // refresh every 1000 milliseconds
```

And now it works, thank you for your help, I really appreciate it, and as usual, I always get to a safer solution after asking it here.